# string sub with alternating replacement

Tags: regex, string

Suppose `x = "hello_world_"`

I want to match all `"_"` and replace them with 1 or 2, in an alternating fashion.  For example `"hello_world_"` would become `"hello1world2"`.  Likewise `"hello_world_how_are_you"` would become `"hello1world2how1are2you"`

I haven't found a version of sub that is vectorized and allows me to pass in an array of replacement strings.  Does such a thing exist?

Comment: Which lang are you running?

Comment: Is the number of underscores in the text always even?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for

```
_([^_]*)_
```

and replace all with

```
1${1}2  # exact syntax depends on the regex flavor/language used.
```

Finally, do a last search for `_` and replace that with `1` in case there was an odd number of underscores.

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/nF9cJ3/1).

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by Tim will work but only for even number of underscores in the text. If you need a more general solution I'd do it in 2 steps. Firstly find and replace with 1 all underscores on odd positions.

Regex expression: `_([^_]*_)?`

Replace expression: `1${1}`

Try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/nF9cJ3/2).

Then find and replace all remaining underscores with 2:

Regex expression: `_`

Replace expression: `2`